# Отрицание в предложении "Я не хочу, чтобы ты думал обо мне плохо"

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, в русском языке возможны эти две версии или (2) нехорошо звучащее предложение? Если два варианта разрешаются, можно утверждать, что отрицание делает особенное ударение на том слове, перед которым стоит?

> (1) *Я не хочу, чтобы ты думал обо мне плохо.*
>
> (2) *Я хочу, чтобы ты не думал обо мне плохо.*

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что оба варианта возможны, но скорее всего они подразумевают разный контекст:

(1) Я **не хочу**, чтобы ты думал обо мне плохо, поэтому я  **не буду делать** того, что может тебе повредить.

(2) Я **хочу**, чтобы ты не думал обо мне плохо, поэтому **постараюсь исправить** то, что  причинило тебе вред.

Получаются такие ситуации: пассивная (не хочу ― не буду делать) и  активная (хочу ― постараюсь исправить).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант (2) - желание исправить ситуацию (ты думаешь обо мне плохо, а я хочу, что бы ты перестал так думать).

Вариант (1) возможен и как превентивное желание, и как желание исправить ситуацию.